# Virtual Environment's Activate Does not work

Tags: python, python-venv

I tried to install VirtualEnv on the latest version of Python. Even though it is successfully installed, when I create a new virtual environment and try to activate it, it switches to a new line as nothing has happened.

I checked the folder, I'm entering the right path, it's not in "bin" folder. I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

I'm on Windows and I'm not using PowerShell.

Comment: Can you show the commands you run? Did you try running `Script\activate.bat` from your venv folder on a command prompt?

Comment: On windows the activate file is venv\Scripts\activate. Is that what you are doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Run Powershell as Administrator

2. Run the following command in powershell: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3. Rerun the activation command: > venv\Scripts\activate.ps1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).